# Android Interpret HttpResponse

Tags: android, http, http-headers

In my App i`m making various http calls from various classes, i want to interpret httpResponse of all these calls to read a particular Header, is there any way i can listen to all these HttpResponse.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have a class from were all http calls are made. If all calls are made from a "webclient" class you can interpret all the responses and deliver the result to the class that request the cal. Using a "webclient" class you can control the connection anyway by giving a handler or a callback as argument.